# python xml.sax error "not well-formed<invalid token>"

Tags: python, xml

Suppose I had the following tags in my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jobs>
<job>
<P class="Beaton"><FONT size=3><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Symbol; COLOR: black; mso-ascii-font-family: 'Times New Roman'">�</SPAN><SPAN style="COLOR: black"><FONT face="Times New Roman"><SPAN style="mso-spacerun: yes">&nbsp; </SPAN>Position accountability<o:p></o:p></FONT></SPAN></FONT></P>
<P class="Beaton"><FONT size=3><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Symbol; COLOR: black; mso-ascii-font-family: 'Times New Roman'">�</SPAN><SPAN style="COLOR: black"><FONT face="Times New Roman"> <SPAN style="mso-spacerun: yes">&nbsp;</SPAN>55 FTEs <o:p></o:p></FONT></SPAN></FONT></P>
</job>
</jobs>
```

and below is my code:

```
from xml.sax.handler import ContentHandler
import xml.sax

xml_path = 'windows/xml_file.xml'

try:
    parser = xml.sax.make_parser( )
    parser.parse(open(xml_path))

except (xml.sax.SAXParseException), e:
        print "*** PARSER error: %s" % e

Result :
*** PARSER error: windows/xml_file.xml:4:113: not well-formed <invalid token>
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong in the p tag and how to avoid this kind of error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably with your `FONT` tag; the value of the `size` attribute should be quoted, otherwise this is simply not valid XML.

You might also run into problems with `&nbsp;`, which is not a valid XML entity (although it is valid in XHTML). Also, your `<jobs>` tag is not closed properly; the last line should be `</jobs>`.

In general, if you have problems with reading XML files, the first thing is always to check whether the XML file is well-formatted. One possible way to do that is by entering it into the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/check).

Comment: Thanks for u r reply and u r right, but for some other tags (I dint pasted here) the values of class attributes and size attributes are not quoted, but even though its working fine, so i am confused and asked here

Comment: Whether the error is of '?' character in the above p tag, because its looking some thing different from the normal ? tag(Assuming in case all the values of attributes are quoted)

Comment: Attribute values in XML _must_ be quoted. Parsers may accept them unquoted but this does not make the XML valid. I don't know about your "?" character, but try removing it and see if the parser accepts it or not. Also, I have just noticed that your `<jobs>` tag is not closed properly.

Comment: thanks for indicating, by mistake i dint closed correctly and i had edited it.Yes i am using xml.sax parser and its not showing any error with quoting values of attributes, but displaying the above error. How to remove this ? tag . Actually when i seen from a eclipse it is showing ? as above. But when i had seen xml file with wordpad it showing just a dot like 'Times New Roman'"> .</SPAN>

Comment: ? is not a tag, it is a character; it is likely some character that cannot be represented in the font you are using, hence it shows as "?". I cannot tell you what it stands for because I don't know where the text is coming from. It is up to you to decide whether you need it or not. If you don't need it, delete it. If you need it, find out what character it stands for, look up its character code in the Unicode code table, and enter the corresponding XML entity (something like `&#XXX;` where `XXX` stands for the hexadecimal character code).

Comment: yes thats right actually i need this how to delete it from th p tag and how to enter the corresponding XML entity, can u provide me an example. Dont mind i am frustating u if u have are free please provide me an example and above information provided is more useful and thanks for that

Comment: Just open an editor, go to the offending ? character in line 4 (and line 5 as well) and delete it. I'm 99.9% sure that you will not need it.

Comment: yes i thought the same, but the actual way i had written actual code is(I dint pasted here) when i run code dynamically it will get the xml of the page from the url and stores in xml_path and will follow the parsing as mentioned, i mean each and evry time when i run the code the xml file in xml_path will be overriden freshly and will parse that. So even though we deleted the data from it, whne i run the code again a fresh xml will stored in the path and contunue parsing agian actually i was stucked here how to delete them dynamically(like we delete spaces, commas during fetching or scraping)

Comment: I mean my actual xml page coming from original url has the format with attribute values not quoted and &nbsp;, so is there anyway to ignore these kind of errors

Comment: Is there anyway to ignore or delete or replace those before sending it to the parser

Comment: Your original source is serving up invalid XML then. (Note that HTML is not XML; if your original source is serving up HTML then you can't simply wrap it in XML tags and consider it valid XML). The easiest way probably is to wrap the part that's coming from outside in `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>` tags. Stuff within a CDATA tag will be treated by the parser literally; it won't be parsed, it will simply be considered as literal data.